# Show actual error in commandline like on Linux

Tags: c, linux, windows, gcc

When running `gcc adventure.c -o adventure` followed by `adventure` in a linux (Ubuntu) terminal will compile it for me, and execute it. When an error occurs (e.g. segmentation fault) during runtime it will report it in the terminal output.

In windows however a runtime error will only pop up a "adventure.c" has stopped working dialog box, and nothing is written to the output of the cmd.exe screen.

Is there some way that I can also get a reported error on Windows when one occurs?

Comment: What does this have to do with C++?

Comment: I thought c and c++ have pretty much the same compilation/execute cycle when keeping with single file programs. I guess i'll remove the C++ tag

Comment: I don't think it's "directly" supported by windows.. But I imagine you could try [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) and [FormatMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: have you tried GDB ?

Comment: I think you can get the behavior you seek if you use cygwin.

Comment: Isn't that a good reason to come back to Linux ? BTW you should compile with `gcc -Wall -g adventure.c -o adventure` while debugging and improving your code, and perhaps `gcc -Wall -O2 adventure.c -o adventure` to compile a mature binary to be redistributed.

Comment: You can also catch the interrupt generated by the crash and then print out a crash dump. Tends to give better results. Re: Windows; Enable crash dumps and you will get a complete crash dump.

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows, you define the subsystem for which you build an executable (ref : [/SUBSYSTEM (Specify Subsystem)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/fcc1zstk.aspx). The two more commons subsystems are `CONSOLE` for command line applications and `WINDOWS` for GUI ones.

As explained in referenced page, the subsystem is normally automatically set to `CONSOLE`by the presence of a standard C `main` function. <del>Normally, the errors related to a `CONSOLE` application are displayed in the console attached to the application, and the errors related to a `WINDOWS` application open a message box.</del>

<del>But I do not know exactly what exists in your adventure version (many exists around ...) - Sniff, I was younger when I played adventure :-) . You should try to generate a minimal console program that SIGSGV (easy in C ..) and verify where the error is displayed.</del>

Edit per comment :

Well after Andrew Medico comment (thanks to him), I did the test and ... he is right :-( ... even a console progam opens the message box by default and does not write anything. Sad ...

So you will have to use [Microsoft structured exception handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/swezty51%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to achieve what you want, but you need to slightly modify source code that way :

- original source :

  ```
  #include ...
  ...

  int main(...) {
     ...
  }
  ```
- modified source

  ```
  #include ...
  #include <excpt.h>
  #include <windows.h>
  ...

  int real_main(...) {
     ...
  }

  int filter(DWORD code, LPEXCEPTION_POINTERS info) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error %x at %x\n", code,
          info->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionAddress);
      return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
  }

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
      int cr;
      __try {
          cr = real_main(...);
      }
      __except(filter(exception_code(), exception_info())) {
          cr = 1;
      }
      return cr;
  }
  ```

All that wraps the original code with a structured exception handler, that catches any fatal error and simply writes the code of the error and the address where the error occurs. As the error has been caught, Windows no longer opens the message box (except under debugger). Normally it would be better to use `FormatMessage` do display the error text, but I could not use it whatever I tried.

A cleaner way would be to use a modified `crt0`, but I do not like to touch to such a thing ...

Comment: This doesn't really help. On Windows, process crashes trigger a dialog box regardless of subsystem. You can suppress the dialog with an environment variable, but you can't change it to print to the console.

Comment: @AndrewMedico : You are right, I edited my post with a structured exception handling solution.

Comment: Your exception handling solution seems ok, by lack of a better default. For actual projects I'd use debuggers or proper error handling, but it's mostly annoying for the small "trying things out on the fly" sort of programs. I'm curious as to why so little others seems to be bothered by this behaviour?